# Angular $httpProvider.interceptor not adding header to request

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have what I thought was a very simple http interceptor. It is not working. Here is the code:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$cookies', function($q, $cookies) {
    return {

      request: function(config) {

        if(config.url.indexOf('my-api-url.com')!==-1) {
          if($cookies.get('sid')) {
            config.headers.Cookie = 'sid='+$cookies.get('sid');
          }
          console.log(config);
        }

        return config;
      }

    }

  }]);
```

The console.log() is outputting a correct-looking object with the "headers" property as follows:

```
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
Cookie: "sid=abcdefg12345thexpectedid54321"
```

But when I go to the network tab in developer tools, the Cookie header has not been added! This seems so simple, I don't even know how I could start debugging this built-in functionality...

Comment: Did you read error in console? There should be an error explaining why it doesn't work.

Comment: Considering I am debugging via the console, I would hope to have seen an error in the console if there was one :P

Comment: My browser (Chorme) reports `Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"`. From here you can find some additional info. Apparently you can't modify this header.

Comment: Ah i see, i am using Firefox. Sorry for the sarcasm earlier. I will see if i can think of another way...